# type '(dynamic) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(Transaction) => Future<dynamic>' of 'action'

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I am trying to insert a record to the DB using SQFLITE in flutter, but It shows this error when calling the insert method.

type '(dynamic) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(Transaction) => Future' of 'action'

My method is:

```
void insertToDB()  {
    db.transaction((txn) {
      txn.rawInsert(
          'INSERT INTO tasks (title, date,time ,status) VALUES ("First task","27/07/2023","9:34 AM","New")')
      .then((val) {
        print("$val inserted successfully");
       }).catchError((error) {
      print('Error while inserting a record ${error.toString()}');
      });
      return null;
    });
  }
```

I am expecting the record is inserted but it does not.

Comment: why you're returning NULL ``return null;`` ?

Comment: it does not work even if I remove 'return null'